# Delete the content of a cell of DatagridView

Tags: .net, datagridview

I am new in VB2008. Could you guys please advice how I can programetically delete the content of a cell of DataGridView?

Say,for example,I have the following code that populates with data in DataGridView. I just want to remove the text of a cell of DataGrid looping through a column. For example,I am using the following code to loop through the GridView and if I I get the text "Test4",I want to remove/delete it from the cell of the GridView. So,only the text "Test4" of cell(1) will be removed.  The GridView is not bound to any database :

Thank you

> Public Class Form1
>
> ```
> Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
>     Dim dt As New DataTable
>     dt.Columns.Add("income")
>     dt.Columns.Add("income1")
>     dt.Columns.Add("sum")
>     dt.Rows.Add("Test1", "Test")
>     dt.Rows.Add("Test2", "Test3")
>     dt.Rows.Add("", "Test4")
>     Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
> End Sub
>
>
> Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>     Dim celldata As String
>
>     For Each r As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
>
>         celldata = r.Cells(1).Value
>         MessageBox.Show(celldata)
>     Next
> End Sub End Class
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you would have to use something like

```
dt.Rows(i).Cells(i).Value = ""
```

I believe that's the format, however, you may have to swap it around a bit.

Comment: Hello GtoXic,thanks for your response!!! I have been successful in removing the content of a cell,if the cell content matches with my criteria. I used the following code to do what I needed :